# Explicit Waits Not Working Using Undetected Chromedriver and Python

Tags: python, selenium, undetected-chromedriver

I am trying to use some explicit waits using Undetected Chromedriver (v2). Rather than executing the statements once the element had loaded, etc it appears to pause until the wait time expires.

When I use the normal selenium chromedriver everything works as expected ("opt-in" is closed in 1-2 seconds) and when I use sleeps instead of waits the statements are executed much quicker.

Can anyone see the problem?

Here's the code:

```
class My_Chrome(uc.Chrome):
    def __del__(self):
        pass

options = uc.ChromeOptions()
arguments = [
    '--log-level=3', '--no-first-run', '--no-service-autorun', '--password-store=basic',
    '--start-maximized',
    '--window-size=1920, 1080',
    '--credentials_enable_service=False',
    '--profile.password_manager_enabled=False,'
    '--add_experimental_option("detach", True)'
]
for argument in arguments:
    options.add_argument(argument)

driver = My_Chrome(options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get('https://www.oddschecker.com')

try:
    opt_in = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Not Now']/..")))
    VirtualClick(driver, opt_in)
    current_time('Closing opt-in')
except:
    pass
```

Comment: Sounds like a limitation of "Undetected Chromedriver (v2)". Why can't you use the latest version of the chromeDriver.exe?

Comment: Seems like a big fail not having such s basic function.